# Merging files data on unix. Proper merge with update and insert in existing file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have below files. I want to merge the files based on 1st field of file.

```
File1

a~1~2~3~4
b~4~6~7~8
c~8~9~10~11
```

File1 is source file and I have received file2 and file3

```
File2

a~5~6~3~4
b~4~6~7~8
d~9~11~12~13

File3

a~51~61~31~41
b~41~62~72~82
e~11~12~13~14
```

So File1 records are updated by latest file we receive. here File3 is latest file. So for record having 1st field a is updated with the values present in File3. Record starting with c has no updates in File2 and File3, so it will remain same. Record e in File3 is new so added to File1. So final content of File1

```
a~51~61~31~41
c~8~9~10~11
b~41~62~72~82
d~9~11~12~13
e~11~12~13~14
```

First I am trying to get common records from all file but below command is extracting common records from only 2 files.

```
awk -F"~" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1; next}$1 in a {print $0}' file1 file2
```

I am working more on it.

Comment: add what you have tried to question

Comment: Update using which criterion?

Comment: "long" and "short" are subjective. Suggest you show your "long" script or at least give a quantitative description of its length and then perhaps someone can tell you whether it can be done with a shorter script and/or more simply.

Comment: edited the question. pls check and let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: try "cat file3 file2 file1 |sort -u -t~ -k1,1"

Comment: @RandomUser please explain your answer. it is working fine

Comment: @Shravan Yadav ,Check answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file3 file2 file1 |sort -u -t~ -k1,1
a~51~61~31~41
b~41~62~72~82
c~8~9~10~11
d~9~11~12~13
e~11~12~13~14
```

Description:

open from file3 to file1 ,then unique and sort them based on first column. Colum delimiter is defined as "~ ".

Answer (score 1):

This awk will work:

```
awk -F'~' '{line[$1]=$0} END {for (key in line) print line[key]}' File{1,2,3}
```

Each new record with a particular key will replace the one that came before it.

The output may not be sorted. Pipe into `sort` or if you use GNU awk then add this to the END block before the loop:

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
```

[ref1](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal), [ref2](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)